# Efficient way to copy data from 10 google sheet files based on two criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I created a single google sheet Masterfile wherein every time I enter data on any of the other google sheet files, it will automatically copy the same record on the Masterfile. There are multiple columns which I need to copy separately from these sheets and I was able to achieve this using ***VLOOKUP based on two criteria***. However, the Masterfile is performing very slow when it executes multiple VLOOKUP on individual columns of the Masterfile.

Here is the formula when I use IMPORTRANGE to copy the data from the other 27 google sheets:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("15jruPpoXmZ8ABbqdvq-kio0lJ61K7f2DdnmbnzrQpuA", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1NHtCTgP5tysHqDml2zwmJCJiJ2JVi7PGJy6ombHL9EE", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1JY2OMkBa926_P_PJABMxFqctfnRQAPAknkvMzFn7lFs", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1JlHRU2vkSWSer_3CFU-TxYYXzXA3vjhFxqOVjmZIWTY", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1LxS-sfcX0Xp-q0fdcekzx1v9KI7-xxBBof2gbeOAPG4", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1T6sKenv9ZwerOzGrLsGnlR3bVWAtAKgzx3q4PKq0sIY", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("15Xh_jZ2SdgQgn8TWaGO6Hp982uSZ6Ixtzg7kmAWthyc", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1b_Y6Avxx81u3VKAFkcrTQUMNjMJ-BAoijaPZpr1xerY", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1nNNZlJkoQV4buyfvbBIeTNGplSxZZyke3huuxudb2-s", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1xPA1f1CO0qMh_MnjwmGk4Y1dYzOqTQUof-mHwwvZasE", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1JC7kXt5wP696s6xfs-7hZ7xFnkdbba5w__lJidsenmc", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1spget0KBDMWHZOZ7Nygr7Llf_3efIbqgkbTpcsqn9R0", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1c-LJFy4tbHpPHb7ep63mYZEENJHpo40lpnZnElC3Wbw", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1kv26cftBOmOBKSglhRGtWG9VRwwxG8lFDlId1sY8-mM", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1IXceiMp2O7EN9YpMkwghuqD303_xR0ecqCSu43hNz6U", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1F72S2u6EvzJkWS1gfDadK7PNykONL9gPoCQo7PC1eNI", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ob-bu08x7b_QfhZRN2e_46PmFezOunrBCEDeJwtrqqs", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1UWcMTinmLBS71_Yr97pPJTzEMcRQwwAgRNyxrqR5mkk", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1vBxul2erb4k_bem4c1osAD3Aht_aKbYYuzQp2Z4rao8", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ih86OTEvjlYF_sw7PVgAgExxBoOm8c48dI5qwA0FDzY", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1NP1bfENxKLZqLrQNKcFeYm8zZh1_aC28WVEla9icMWs", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1PxgbiYTeeG-mbmVa9zw0eFAU6WkyO7yDlI661P8MOhM", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1TPXhSjBBEsNFB8kwWUYw7Cs5bcKNz02a7EsPRtWi9PI", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1LjB7z5mUUeou0mUJp4Df4hxSBpniIY9Z1jHX33UQo6w", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1zgg4J9F1sEz2RmfWShaQdDRVT3hm6ltXTPWD4MR3ISI", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1zxbZ9k2BZI-7L_F2T4t3iLpPpcVgbscp1Op34PmjFPI", "Sheet1!A2:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1qR04z7PqJvyDn_nSFya-lhHMxGdX6C1Z_PopBz6ysDA", "Sheet1!A2:H")},
 "WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col1 ASC")
```

And here is the sample formula I use to copy data from the sheets based on two criteria:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&" "&B2, {
 IMPORTRANGE("15jruPpoXmZ8ABbqdvq-kio0lJ61K7f2DdnmbnzrQpuA", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("15jruPpoXmZ8ABbqdvq-kio0lJ61K7f2DdnmbnzrQpuA", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("15jruPpoXmZ8ABbqdvq-kio0lJ61K7f2DdnmbnzrQpuA", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1NHtCTgP5tysHqDml2zwmJCJiJ2JVi7PGJy6ombHL9EE", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1NHtCTgP5tysHqDml2zwmJCJiJ2JVi7PGJy6ombHL9EE", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1NHtCTgP5tysHqDml2zwmJCJiJ2JVi7PGJy6ombHL9EE", "Sheet2!E2:E"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1JY2OMkBa926_P_PJABMxFqctfnRQAPAknkvMzFn7lFs", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1JY2OMkBa926_P_PJABMxFqctfnRQAPAknkvMzFn7lFs", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1JY2OMkBa926_P_PJABMxFqctfnRQAPAknkvMzFn7lFs", "Sheet2!E2:E"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1JlHRU2vkSWSer_3CFU-TxYYXzXA3vjhFxqOVjmZIWTY", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1JlHRU2vkSWSer_3CFU-TxYYXzXA3vjhFxqOVjmZIWTY", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1JlHRU2vkSWSer_3CFU-TxYYXzXA3vjhFxqOVjmZIWTY", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1LxS-sfcX0Xp-q0fdcekzx1v9KI7-xxBBof2gbeOAPG4", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1LxS-sfcX0Xp-q0fdcekzx1v9KI7-xxBBof2gbeOAPG4", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1LxS-sfcX0Xp-q0fdcekzx1v9KI7-xxBBof2gbeOAPG4", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1T6sKenv9ZwerOzGrLsGnlR3bVWAtAKgzx3q4PKq0sIY", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1T6sKenv9ZwerOzGrLsGnlR3bVWAtAKgzx3q4PKq0sIY", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1T6sKenv9ZwerOzGrLsGnlR3bVWAtAKgzx3q4PKq0sIY", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("15Xh_jZ2SdgQgn8TWaGO6Hp982uSZ6Ixtzg7kmAWthyc", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("15Xh_jZ2SdgQgn8TWaGO6Hp982uSZ6Ixtzg7kmAWthyc", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("15Xh_jZ2SdgQgn8TWaGO6Hp982uSZ6Ixtzg7kmAWthyc", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1b_Y6Avxx81u3VKAFkcrTQUMNjMJ-BAoijaPZpr1xerY", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1b_Y6Avxx81u3VKAFkcrTQUMNjMJ-BAoijaPZpr1xerY", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1b_Y6Avxx81u3VKAFkcrTQUMNjMJ-BAoijaPZpr1xerY", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1nNNZlJkoQV4buyfvbBIeTNGplSxZZyke3huuxudb2-s", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1nNNZlJkoQV4buyfvbBIeTNGplSxZZyke3huuxudb2-s", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1nNNZlJkoQV4buyfvbBIeTNGplSxZZyke3huuxudb2-s", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1xPA1f1CO0qMh_MnjwmGk4Y1dYzOqTQUof-mHwwvZasE", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1xPA1f1CO0qMh_MnjwmGk4Y1dYzOqTQUof-mHwwvZasE", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1xPA1f1CO0qMh_MnjwmGk4Y1dYzOqTQUof-mHwwvZasE", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1JC7kXt5wP696s6xfs-7hZ7xFnkdbba5w__lJidsenmc", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1JC7kXt5wP696s6xfs-7hZ7xFnkdbba5w__lJidsenmc", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1JC7kXt5wP696s6xfs-7hZ7xFnkdbba5w__lJidsenmc", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1spget0KBDMWHZOZ7Nygr7Llf_3efIbqgkbTpcsqn9R0", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1spget0KBDMWHZOZ7Nygr7Llf_3efIbqgkbTpcsqn9R0", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1spget0KBDMWHZOZ7Nygr7Llf_3efIbqgkbTpcsqn9R0", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1c-LJFy4tbHpPHb7ep63mYZEENJHpo40lpnZnElC3Wbw", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1c-LJFy4tbHpPHb7ep63mYZEENJHpo40lpnZnElC3Wbw", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1c-LJFy4tbHpPHb7ep63mYZEENJHpo40lpnZnElC3Wbw", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1kv26cftBOmOBKSglhRGtWG9VRwwxG8lFDlId1sY8-mM", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1kv26cftBOmOBKSglhRGtWG9VRwwxG8lFDlId1sY8-mM", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1kv26cftBOmOBKSglhRGtWG9VRwwxG8lFDlId1sY8-mM", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1IXceiMp2O7EN9YpMkwghuqD303_xR0ecqCSu43hNz6U", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1IXceiMp2O7EN9YpMkwghuqD303_xR0ecqCSu43hNz6U", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1IXceiMp2O7EN9YpMkwghuqD303_xR0ecqCSu43hNz6U", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1F72S2u6EvzJkWS1gfDadK7PNykONL9gPoCQo7PC1eNI", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1F72S2u6EvzJkWS1gfDadK7PNykONL9gPoCQo7PC1eNI", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1F72S2u6EvzJkWS1gfDadK7PNykONL9gPoCQo7PC1eNI", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ob-bu08x7b_QfhZRN2e_46PmFezOunrBCEDeJwtrqqs", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ob-bu08x7b_QfhZRN2e_46PmFezOunrBCEDeJwtrqqs", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ob-bu08x7b_QfhZRN2e_46PmFezOunrBCEDeJwtrqqs", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1UWcMTinmLBS71_Yr97pPJTzEMcRQwwAgRNyxrqR5mkk", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1UWcMTinmLBS71_Yr97pPJTzEMcRQwwAgRNyxrqR5mkk", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1UWcMTinmLBS71_Yr97pPJTzEMcRQwwAgRNyxrqR5mkk", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1vBxul2erb4k_bem4c1osAD3Aht_aKbYYuzQp2Z4rao8", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1vBxul2erb4k_bem4c1osAD3Aht_aKbYYuzQp2Z4rao8", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1vBxul2erb4k_bem4c1osAD3Aht_aKbYYuzQp2Z4rao8", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ih86OTEvjlYF_sw7PVgAgExxBoOm8c48dI5qwA0FDzY", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ih86OTEvjlYF_sw7PVgAgExxBoOm8c48dI5qwA0FDzY", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ih86OTEvjlYF_sw7PVgAgExxBoOm8c48dI5qwA0FDzY", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1NP1bfENxKLZqLrQNKcFeYm8zZh1_aC28WVEla9icMWs", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1NP1bfENxKLZqLrQNKcFeYm8zZh1_aC28WVEla9icMWs", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1NP1bfENxKLZqLrQNKcFeYm8zZh1_aC28WVEla9icMWs", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1PxgbiYTeeG-mbmVa9zw0eFAU6WkyO7yDlI661P8MOhM", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1PxgbiYTeeG-mbmVa9zw0eFAU6WkyO7yDlI661P8MOhM", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1PxgbiYTeeG-mbmVa9zw0eFAU6WkyO7yDlI661P8MOhM", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1TPXhSjBBEsNFB8kwWUYw7Cs5bcKNz02a7EsPRtWi9PI", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1TPXhSjBBEsNFB8kwWUYw7Cs5bcKNz02a7EsPRtWi9PI", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1TPXhSjBBEsNFB8kwWUYw7Cs5bcKNz02a7EsPRtWi9PI", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1LjB7z5mUUeou0mUJp4Df4hxSBpniIY9Z1jHX33UQo6w", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1LjB7z5mUUeou0mUJp4Df4hxSBpniIY9Z1jHX33UQo6w", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1LjB7z5mUUeou0mUJp4Df4hxSBpniIY9Z1jHX33UQo6w", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1zgg4J9F1sEz2RmfWShaQdDRVT3hm6ltXTPWD4MR3ISI", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1zgg4J9F1sEz2RmfWShaQdDRVT3hm6ltXTPWD4MR3ISI", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1zgg4J9F1sEz2RmfWShaQdDRVT3hm6ltXTPWD4MR3ISI", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1zxbZ9k2BZI-7L_F2T4t3iLpPpcVgbscp1Op34PmjFPI", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1zxbZ9k2BZI-7L_F2T4t3iLpPpcVgbscp1Op34PmjFPI", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1zxbZ9k2BZI-7L_F2T4t3iLpPpcVgbscp1Op34PmjFPI", "Sheet2!E2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1qR04z7PqJvyDn_nSFya-lhHMxGdX6C1Z_PopBz6ysDA", "Sheet2!A2:A")&" "&
 IMPORTRANGE("1qR04z7PqJvyDn_nSFya-lhHMxGdX6C1Z_PopBz6ysDA", "Sheet2!B2:B"),
 IMPORTRANGE("1qR04z7PqJvyDn_nSFya-lhHMxGdX6C1Z_PopBz6ysDA", "Sheet2!E2:E")}, 2, )))
```

My question would be is there an efficient way for me to achieve the result I am aiming to get aside from VLOOKUP? as vlookup is really slow for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

in this case, the recommended solution would be to use an intermediate spreadsheet with 2 formulae and then you import the final product into your sheet. vlookup is pretty fast fx but every iportrange fx has a toll on it. with that much importranges it is just expected overall fx to drop on performance.

create a new spreadsheet and paste this into A1:

```
=SORT(QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("15jruPpoXmZ8ABbqdvq-kio0lJ61K7f2DdnmbnzrQpuA", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1NHtCTgP5tysHqDml2zwmJCJiJ2JVi7PGJy6ombHL9EE", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1JY2OMkBa926_P_PJABMxFqctfnRQAPAknkvMzFn7lFs", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1JlHRU2vkSWSer_3CFU-TxYYXzXA3vjhFxqOVjmZIWTY", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1LxS-sfcX0Xp-q0fdcekzx1v9KI7-xxBBof2gbeOAPG4", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1T6sKenv9ZwerOzGrLsGnlR3bVWAtAKgzx3q4PKq0sIY", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("15Xh_jZ2SdgQgn8TWaGO6Hp982uSZ6Ixtzg7kmAWthyc", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1b_Y6Avxx81u3VKAFkcrTQUMNjMJ-BAoijaPZpr1xerY", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1nNNZlJkoQV4buyfvbBIeTNGplSxZZyke3huuxudb2-s", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1xPA1f1CO0qMh_MnjwmGk4Y1dYzOqTQUof-mHwwvZasE", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1JC7kXt5wP696s6xfs-7hZ7xFnkdbba5w__lJidsenmc", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1spget0KBDMWHZOZ7Nygr7Llf_3efIbqgkbTpcsqn9R0", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1c-LJFy4tbHpPHb7ep63mYZEENJHpo40lpnZnElC3Wbw", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1kv26cftBOmOBKSglhRGtWG9VRwwxG8lFDlId1sY8-mM", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1IXceiMp2O7EN9YpMkwghuqD303_xR0ecqCSu43hNz6U", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1F72S2u6EvzJkWS1gfDadK7PNykONL9gPoCQo7PC1eNI", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ob-bu08x7b_QfhZRN2e_46PmFezOunrBCEDeJwtrqqs", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1UWcMTinmLBS71_Yr97pPJTzEMcRQwwAgRNyxrqR5mkk", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1vBxul2erb4k_bem4c1osAD3Aht_aKbYYuzQp2Z4rao8", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1Ih86OTEvjlYF_sw7PVgAgExxBoOm8c48dI5qwA0FDzY", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1NP1bfENxKLZqLrQNKcFeYm8zZh1_aC28WVEla9icMWs", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1PxgbiYTeeG-mbmVa9zw0eFAU6WkyO7yDlI661P8MOhM", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1TPXhSjBBEsNFB8kwWUYw7Cs5bcKNz02a7EsPRtWi9PI", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1LjB7z5mUUeou0mUJp4Df4hxSBpniIY9Z1jHX33UQo6w", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1zgg4J9F1sEz2RmfWShaQdDRVT3hm6ltXTPWD4MR3ISI", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1zxbZ9k2BZI-7L_F2T4t3iLpPpcVgbscp1Op34PmjFPI", "Sheet1!A2:E");
 IMPORTRANGE("1qR04z7PqJvyDn_nSFya-lhHMxGdX6C1Z_PopBz6ysDA", "Sheet1!A2:E")},
 "WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL", IFERROR(NOW()/0)))
```

in F1 use:

```
={FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:B),,9^9)), E:E}
```

in spreadsheet settings you can set recalculation like:

[image]

then in your final sheet, you will just use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&" "&B2:B, 
 IMPORTRANGE("id", "Sheet1!F:G"), 2, IFERROR(NOW()/0))
```